# JSON with french character in raw folder

Tags: android

I have a json file in my raw folder with the name of school.json. I want to parse that json using following code and put that it in to listview but it gives me some unknown character in my list because of a french character in json file. So how do I fix this french character.

```
 { "Records" : { "Record" : [ 
              { "Row" : { "A" : "Collège",
                    "B" : "8/22/2013",
                    "C" : "8/23/2013"
                  } },
              { "Row" : { "A" : "Collège",
                    "B" : "8/23/2013"
                  } },
              { "Row" : { "A" : "D'Anjou",
                    "B" : "8/23/2013"
                  } },
              { "Row" : { "A" : "Collège",
                    "B" : "8/26/2013"
                  } },
              { "Row" : { "A" : "Collège",
                    "B" : "8/26/2013"
                  } },
              { "Row" : { "A" : "Collège",
                    "B" : "8/26/2013"
                  } },

              { "Row" : { "A" : "School",
                    "B" : "9/20/2013"
                  } }
            ] } }
```

//-----------------my method

```
public String getJson() {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.school);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                int n;

                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return writer.toString();
    }
```

Comment: im not sure but try with `readLine()` maybe.

Comment: String json = "";
try {
    BufferedInputStream resourceStream = new BufferedInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.brand));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceStream));

    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        json += line;
    }
    reader.close();
    resourceStream.close();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    Log.e("myApp", ex.getMessage());
}

Comment: solved using reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);